# Creating Materials Via API With Appearance Asset

Tags: ironpython, revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell

I have a CSV File with RGB Values that im using to create materials in Revit through Dynamo Python scripting, However the materials that are created does not have AppearanceAsset assigned to it(even though it has a appearance asset tab}.Since when i get the AppearanceAssetID for the Material it Returns '-1' which as per the API means there is no assigned asset to it.

How do i create materials with Appearance IDs already assigned

I want to access the Appearance asset and set the Color to it, Since normally only the **graphics** color is set and not the **appearance** Color.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager
clr.AddReference('RevitNodes')
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)


def ToRevitColor(dynamoColor):return Color(dynamoColor.Red, dynamoColor.Green, dynamoColor.Blue)
def ToDynamoObject(revitObject, isRevitOwned=False):return revitObject.ToDSType(isRevitOwned)
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

newMaterials = []
appassetid = []

TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)

mat_name = IN[0]
color = IN[1]


for i,y in zip (mat_name, color):
    new_mat_id = Material.Create(doc, i)
    new_mat = doc.GetElement(new_mat_id)
    new_mat.Color = ToRevitColor(y)
    newMaterials.append(ToDynamoObject(new_mat))
    appassetid.append(new_mat.AppearanceAssetId)


TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()

OUT = newMaterials,appassetid
```

[image: material Created Graphics tab]

[image: material Created appearance tab]

[image: output for getting appearance asset ID]

http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/d02d0677-341a-8d1a-d3eb-35ff82f01695.htm

the API Reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was satisfactorily resolved and confirmed in the Revit API discussion forum [creating materials With appearance asset](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/creating-materials-with-appearance-asset/m-p/8333781).